# html question - button over anchor?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, anchor

```
<button onclick="aprove(<?php echo $d["cod_team"]; ?>)">Aprove</button>
<button onclick="refuse(<?php echo $d["cod_team"] ?>)">Refuse</button>
```

1) How can we give this same instructions to a A element?
2) Are there any cross-browser issues that I should be aware of?

K. Regards,
MEM

Comment: So the question is either to use # or javascript:void(0) so I believe, no? I mean, it will be preferable calling the js part on the appropriate event handler instead of href? If this is not liquid, I prefer not to be answered. The advantage of using void instead of # is that the SCROLL will not move "unexpectedly" to the user. Am I right? Thanks in advance again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:aprove(<?php echo $d["cod_team"]; ?>)">Approve</a>
<a href="javascript:refuse(<?php echo $d["cod_team"]; ?>)">Refuse</a>
```

Also:

```
<a href="#" onclick="aprove(<?php echo $d["cod_team"]; ?>)">;return false;">Approve</a>
<a href="#" onclick="refuse(<?php echo $d["cod_team"]; ?>)">;return false;">Refuse</a>
```

And, just for grins:

```
<a href="javascript:aprove(<?=$d["cod_team"]?>)">Approve</a>
<a href="javascript:refuse(<?=$d["cod_team"]?>)">Refuse</a>
```

And if you want a fallback:

```
<a href="approve.php?cod_team=<?=$d["cod_team"]?>" onclick="aprove(<?=$d["cod_team"]?>)">;return false;">Approve</a>
<a href="refuse.php?cod_team=<?=$d["cod_team"]?>" onclick="refuse(<?=$d["cod_team"]?>)">;return false;">Refuse</a>
```

Plus, there are other ways innumerate.

By the way, you misspelled approve in the function name.

Comment: 1 up for the English lesson. ;)

Comment: :) I just figured it was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" onclick="...">Approve</a>
```

The `#` for the url guarantees that the browser won't leave this page, and otherwise the semantics would stay the same.

Comment: You can omit the href attribute on the anchor tag and it will work fine (not leave the page).

Comment: True, but some stupid browsers won't honor click-related actions (such as :hover/:active css stuff) on a tags without the href.

Answer (score 1):

same way:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="aprove(<?php echo $d["cod_team"]; ?>)">Aprove</a>
```

The javascript:void(0) part prevents the default behavior of the href thus preventing any page from loading.

Comment: Thanks for void(0) explanation I've seen it so many times but never knew, even more or less, the reason for doing so. :)